# How to check if a method argument implements multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, constraints

Is there any way to use constraints to check if a method argument is implementing more than one interface?

Take this simple example which checks if TResponse has implemented IBaseSearchResponse :

```
public static TResponse Search<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest args)
    where TResponse : IBaseSearchResponse {}
```

But i want to also know if it implements IBaseSearchProps.
Ive tried to add a constraint by doing things like:

```
public static TResponse Search<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest args)
    where TResponse : IBaseSearchArgs where TResponse : IBaseSearchProps {}
```

But this reports a constraints clause already used for type TResponse
And:

```
public static TResponse Search<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest args)
    where TResponse : (IBaseSearchArgs && IBaseSearchProps) {}
```

this is just illegal syntax

I apologize in advance if my question is ill prepared, answered elsewhere or if the answer is defined in the c# spec..., i did at least take a look for it here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you'll need to separate them by a comma (`,`):

e.g.

```
public static TResponse Search<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest args)
where TResponse : IBaseSearchArgs , IBaseSearchProps {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a comma-delimited list:

```
public void F<T>(T t) 
    where T : IEnumerable, IFooBar
{
}
```